# How to scale accumulative data for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am trying to create a machine learning model that should be able to decide whether to help a user in a serious game which aims to learn programming. It will be a binary classifier.

The features (independent variables) are a count of the actions performed by the user since the beginning of the current level. For example:

- number of times the explanatory content "for loop" has been consulted (integer values: 0, 1, 2, etc.)
- number of times the student has copied the "for loop" content (integer values: 0, 1, 2, etc.)
- number of times the student implemented a "for loop" (integer values: 0, 1, 2, etc.)
- number of syntax errors (integer values: 0, 1, 2, etc.)
  [...]
- time passed since the beginning of the level (number of milliseconds: 123,345 ms)

The label of the instances (dependent variable) is:

- Student was helped (Boolean value: 0 = No / 1 = Yes)

For information, the dataset is highly imbalanced, because the ratio of positive instances oscillates between 0.1% and 0.5% depending on the level.

Here are the histograms of my features: [image]

I am trying different kinds of binary classifiers: Random Forest, SVM, Logistic Regression, etc.

Some of them require the data to be scaled.

My features are accumulative, so they do not follow a normal distribution.

Which method should I use for scaling? Normalization, standardization? Other? Thanks in advance for your help!

Matthieu

---

As a beginner, I really need help and expert insight to create my machine learning model.

My features are cumulative action counts over time. For example:

- level_time_spent = 15,340 ms
- nb_for_simple_viewed = 2
- nb_for_counter_0_copied = 0
- nb_syntactic_error = 3
- nb_if_branch_concept_implemented = 3
- notion_help_received (label) = 0

or

- level_time_spent = 123,340 ms
- nb_for_simple_viewed = 5
- nb_for_counter_0_copied = 1
- nb_syntactic_error = 8
- nb_if_branch_concept_implemented = 0
- notion_help_received (label) = 1

1. I wonder what distribution my random variables have? Is it a Poisson distribution? Is this kind of distribution compatible with machine learning techniques?
2. I need to scale the features for some algorithms (in particular SVM and linear Regression). The standardization is obviously not adapted (non-normal distribution). Can the min-max scaler do the job? Should I use Box-Cox transform or Yeo-Johnson transform?

Thanks for helping me, I'm a bit lost!

Matthieu